# How can I remove duplicate array elements by value and keep the latest entry?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Here is my query, the inner query gives me an array sorted by date, but if I use group by it keeps a random duplicate rather than the first or last one. In my case, there may be multiple appointments with the same patient id, but I only need the latest. Is there a way I can either use php to keep the first occurence of a duplicate value and remove the rest while keeping the date sort or do it in a query?

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT a.patient_id, a.appointment_datetime, b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email 
    FROM '.TABLE_APPOINTMENTS.' a, '.TABLE_PATIENTS.' b 
    WHERE doctor_id='.$doctor_id.' AND a.patient_id = b.id 
    ORDER BY appointment_datetime desc) AS t 
GROUP BY patient_id';
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [patient_id] => 1 [appointment_datetime] => 
 [1] =>  Array ( [patient_id] => 2 [appointment_datetime] => ) 
[2] => Array ( [patient_id] => 3 [appointment_datetime] => )
 [3] => Array ( [patient_id] => 5 [appointment_datetime] => 
[4] => Array ( [patient_id] => 20 [appointment_datetime] => 2016-06-29 17:30:00 ) )
```

output of inner query:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [patient_id] => 20 [appointment_datetime] => 2016-07-14 17:00:00 
) [1] =>Array ( [patient_id] => 20 [appointment_datetime] => 2016-07-05 23:00:00 ) 
[2] => Array ( [patient_id] => 20 [appointment_datetime] => 2016-06-29 17:30:00 ) 
[3] => Array ( [patient_id] => 20 [appointment_datetime] => 
 [4] =>Array ( [patient_id] => 20 [appointment_datetime] => )
 [5] = Array ( [patient_id] => 20 [appointment_datetime] => )
[6] => Array ( [patient_id] => 1 [appointment_datetime] => ) 
[7] => Array ( [patient_id] => 2 [appointment_datetime] => ) 
[8] => Array ( [patient_id] => 3 [appointment_datetime] => )
[9] => Array ( [patient_id] => 5 [appointment_datetime] => ) )
```

solution:

```
$sql = 'SELECT a.patient_id, max(a.appointment_datetime), b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email 
    FROM '.TABLE_APPOINTMENTS.' a, '.TABLE_PATIENTS.' b 
    WHERE doctor_id='.$doctor_id.' AND a.patient_id = b.id 
    GROUP BY a.patient_id ORDER BY a.appointment_datetime';
```

Comment: can you post the output of this  query?

Comment: Add another field to your order by.  The problem here is that you are saying you want to keep the "first one" but you aren't defining what that means when the dates are the same.

Comment: added the output. @user3137702, I mean the first instance of a duplicate, there can't/won't be two with the same dates (except null), but either way if a duplicate of the id value exists I only need it once. I am displaying the data so when I do a foreach loop I don't want there to be anything extra and it should be ordered by most recent appointments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying that you want the latest entry directly in your query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT a.patient_id, MAX(a.appointment_datetime), b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email 
            FROM '.TABLE_APPOINTMENTS.' a, '.TABLE_PATIENTS.' b 
            WHERE doctor_id='.$doctor_id.' AND a.patient_id = b.id 
            ORDER BY appointment_datetime desc) AS t 
    GROUP BY patient_id';
```

Notice the MAX() added to the query.

Good luck!

Comment: This only gives one entry with the max datetime, but I'll try to get it to work thanks.

Comment: Worked great with a couple tweaks!

Answer (score 1):

User in_array to remove duplicate values and then Try pushing unique values to the new array.

```
$unique = array();
foreach($array as $arr)
{
if(!in_array($arr, $unique))
{
$unique[] = $arr;
}
}
```

With this you will get all the first values. and all the duplicate will be removed. Use this concept in your array values. It will work like a charm